# DirectX 11 - Bullet Debug Draw

Tags: c++, directx, lines, bullet

I am using Bullet Physics in my own DirectX 11 Game Engine and i want to use the debug draw class provided by bullet. Basicly you are creating a class, that receives all the lines that should be drawn by bullet. Is there an easy and fast way to just draw a 3D Line in DirectX 11 (preferably without using buffers and shaders and all that stuff)?

Comment: Do you want to tell me that there is no way to draw a Line in DirectX11??? Somebody??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. You need to create a vertex buffer with the line points. If you want to draw multiple lines, put all your vertices in one buffer to optimize for performance.

Because the FFP has been removed in DirectX 10, you need a simple shader. The vertex shader probably just transforms the vertices with view and projection transform and the pixel shader returns a constant color (depending on your needs).

You would then draw the vertex buffer with an appropriate topology (line list).

The reason why there are no easy methods (like Jesus Ramos' answer or OpenGL's `glBegin(GL_LINES)`) is that they cannot be implemented efficiently. It is always necessary to transfer more data to the GPU than needed. That's why it's up to the programmer to write efficient code using buffers.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. The only problem is, that I have to recreate the buffer often, because the amount of lines that have to be drawn change a lot... That's why I was seeking for a bufferless method.

Comment: I assume by recreating the buffer you mean changing its data. Creating a buffer takes a lot of time.

Comment: No. I meant recreating. I know, changing it's data (updating it) would be faster, but the number of vertices that need to be stored in the buffer change a lot (possibly every frame). That's why I didn't want to use buffers...

Comment: Then use a buffer that is big enough. It can have some unassigned space. If that prevents the recreation. You could maintain buffers of different sizes and choose the appropriate one based on your vertex data.

Comment: I tried using a big buffer and leaving unassigned space. It works well, but would it be efficient if I create a buffer for only 1 line (so 2 vertices) and do instanced drawing for every line?

Comment: How do you think that would work? You still need a buffer with the line vertices.

Comment: Create 1 buffer with space for 2 vertices (= 1 line). For every `drawLine(...)` call put the given information into the buffer and draw it. To make it faster (i guess) use instanced drawing!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LP3DXLINE` and call `D3DXCreateLine` to draw a simple line. Calling `Draw` with an array of length 2 (start, end) for your line and it should work.

EDIT: This is apparently only DX9. Leaving answer here just in case it helps someone else.

Comment: The funny thing is, when I google for `LP3DXLINE` I only get 2 links to this StackOverflow Question!

Comment: Also, those functions only work for DirectX 9! I am using DirectX 11.

Comment: @theCNG27 I only ever did dx9. I stopped dx development and switched to opengl and never went back. I was just running off of memory from before :)

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of using a triangle in lit wire-frame and making 2 of the verts the same location:
x1y1z1,x2y2z2,x2y2z2
I do this in DBPro and it works.

Comment: It's possible but you still need a buffer to draw those triangles. Drawing lines with a buffer is no problem but without buffer it's not possible. I solved the problem by using one buffer multiple times per frame. By that I am not limited to the buffer size and fully dynamic.